# how to set a view controller as an delegate in app delegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I have a `signupcontroller` for which I check if user is logged in , if not then I present it in `appdelegate`, also as this `signupcontroller` has been subclassed for customisation hence `delegates` are being used to talk to events like input validation before sending to server, my question is how set a delegate in `appdelegate` on a `UIViewController`?(can't use `signUpController.delegate = self`;) It shows  a warning "sending 'xxxviewcontroller strong' to a parameter of incompatible type 'id

Simply Put I want to set some view controller as delegate not in that view controller but in appdelegate

Comment: Why can't you use signUpController.delegate ? Do you get an error or warning ?

Comment: can u explain in more detail and simplified manner..the way u have asked the question is very complicated...

Comment: it shows a warning "sending 'xxxviewcontroller strong' to a parameter of incompatible type 'id<xxxloginViewControllerDelegate>'

Comment: I would guess your `xxxviewcontroller` does not conform to the `xxxloginViewControllerDelegate`. In `xxxviewcontroller.h` you need to have `@interface xxxviewcontroller<xxxloginViewControllerDelegate>`. Was that it?

Comment: no, i simply want to set some view controller as delegate not in that view controller but in appdelegate